# Окно закрытия приложения

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно будет реализовать.
У меня имеется окно закрытия приложения (при нажатии на кнопку *назад* из главного экрана появляется диалоговое окно с двумя кнопками: *выйти* и *закрыть окно*). Такую мини-систему мне нужно использовать в двух разных классах.
Придется дважды создавать этот код в двух классах, либо есть какие-то другие методы сделать код более гибким?

Comment: ты можешь создать родительский класс, написать код диалога в нём. В двух разных классах ты наследуешься от этого родительского класса и вызываешь в них метод родительского класса, который отображает диалог. Чтоб диалог был с разным содержимым, просто принимай на вход метода нужные данные и подставляй внутри метода в родительском классе. Метод не должен быть `private`

Comment: А как быть, если нужная мне функция поддерживается только с AppCompatActivity? Я говорю о getSupportActionBar.

Comment: а ты наследуй родительский класс от `AppCompatActivity` и эта функция перейдёт через родительский класс в твои 2 класса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты можешь создать родительский класс, написать код диалога в нём.

В двух разных классах ты наследуешься от этого родительского класса и вызываешь в них метод родительского класса, который отображает диалог.

Чтоб диалог был с разным содержимым, просто принимай на вход метода нужные данные и подставляй внутри метода в родительском классе. Метод не должен быть `private`.

**Например, родитель с методом для диалога:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void showAlert(Context context){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Заголовок")
                .setMessage("Содержимое")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNegativeButton("Отмена",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                //при необходимости какой-то код на отмену...
                                //...
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                .setPositiveButton("Ок",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                //при необходимости какой-то код на принятие...
                                //...
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });


        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

**И твои активити, которые наследуются от родительского класса (BaseActivity):**

```
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        showAlert(this);
    }

}
```

В итоге ты вызываешь метод

> showAlert(this);

который написан в `BaseActivity` в любом классе, который наследуется от него.

Если нужно изменять диалог в зависимости от экрана, то можно добавить дополнительные аргументы в метод в классе `BaseActivity`